# Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcms`

Tags: androidx, android-d8

unable to find out what is error plzz help me,after migrate to android x this error is coming ,i updates my all dependencies and android also
but it showing this error
Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcms`.